# Linux semaphores, shared across forked->exec'd processes?

Tags: c++, linux, synchronization, ipc, semaphore

Suppose I have a parent that forks a child. The forked child then uses exec() to change it's process image. Both child and parent are now doing active data exchange using a pipe. I want to synchonize this data exchange using a semaphore. From what I understand I will create the semaphore in the parent before fork. However will the child, after exec() be able to access this semaphore?
If not, is there some other way I can use a semaphore to establish synchonization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [exec man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/execlp.html):
`[SEM]  Any named semaphores open in the calling process shall be closed as if by appropriate calls to sem_close().`

So after calling exec, you can't reach any open semephores in the parent.

Of course, you don't have to worry about that at all, if you want two processes to share a semaphore just use [posix named semaphores](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview).

The idea is simple, you create a semaphore in a process and give it a name; the other process just has to have the name and it then can open that semaphore.